# MySql Join two tables with multiple columns

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have two tables

### tblcities:

```
id |   name        
----------------
 1 | Bahawalpur   
 2 | Multan
 3 | Karachi
 4 | Lahore
```

### tblflights:

```
id | from_city_id | to_city_id
-------------------------------
 1 |      1       |     2 
 2 |      3       |     4
 3 |      2       |     1
```

I want to join tables so it shows the city name for both columns i.e: from_city_id & to_city_id

what i tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM tblflights
JOIN tblcities
ON tblflights.from_city_id = tblcities.id
```

### result:

```
    id | from_city_id | to_city_id |   name 
    --------------------------------------------
     1 |      1       |     2      |  Bahawalpur
     2 |      3       |     4      |  Karachi
     3 |      2       |     1      |  Multan
```

but i want name of both cities (from_city_id & to_city_id)

i tried my best but could not found any solution.

i am using CodeIgniter

Comment: Join 2 copies of cities to flights.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.

```
SELECT tf.id, tc1.name from_city_name, tc2.name to_city_name
FROM tblflights tf
JOIN tblcities tc1
ON tf.from_city_id = tc1.id
JOIN tblcities tc2
ON tf.from_city_id = tc2.id;
```

You may need to remove duplicates depending on your table contents.